# wordpress php function to a custom page if url end with specific string

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We need to apply a certain css or a php funciton only when a url ends with a specific string, we found a way when it has a specific string as a part of the url using the **strpos**, but we need it to work only when the string is in the end of the url not just a part of url

```
    add_action( 'init', 'admin_count_css' );
    function admin_count_css() {


    $url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if ( (false !== strpos( $url, 'post_type=posts' ) ) ) {
    echo '<style type="text/css">
         span.count{
         display:none !important;
         }
         </style>';
}

    }
```

It work as it checks the url and checks if **post_type=posts** part of the url or not and then apply the css, we need it to check if that string is at the end of the url or no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this function before `admin_count_css()` function

```
function endsWith($string, $endString) 
{ 
    $len = strlen($endString); 
    if ($len == 0) { 
        return true; 
    } 
    return (substr($string, -$len) === $endString); 
}
```

Then replace `if ( (false !== strpos( $url, 'post_type=posts' ) ) ) {` with this code

```
if (endsWith($url,'post_type=posts')) {
```